# expand single object functionality

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm new in objective-C and i wonder if its correct:
I have a class

```
@interface BaseClass : NSObject
```

And then i created object of that class:

```
BaseClass *baseClassObject = [[BaseClass alloc] initWith...];
```

After that i have another class:

```
@interface AdvancedClass : BaseClass
```

Depends on what data i'm getting in BaseClass (object initializer, methods later) i may want to expand functionality of object. So i want to baseClassObject become object from AdvancedClass class.

1) Is this correct?
2) Is this possible to "promote" object like that?

Comment: "i may decide that my baseClassObject have to expand functionality to method from AdvancedClass" <- this sentence doesn't really make sense. Could you please precise it?

Comment: I've just edit my question. Hope i expressed myself clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible and correct -- that's called polymorphism and it's one of the major principles of object-oriented programming. You simply create instances of the base class or the subclass in your methods depending on what kind of functionality you need.

Comment: I think this answer is incorrect - the OP is asking if he can promote an instance of BaseClass to an instance of SubClass.

Comment: Well -- From OP's question, I thought he wanted to override initializer methods based on input data. Anyway, the question is not 100% proper English and it may be the case that I misunderstood it -- could you please describe what do you think OP asks?

Answer (score 1):

No, if you have an instance of `BaseClass` you cannot treat it as if it were an instance of `AdvanceClass` nor can you magically 'promote' it to an instance of `AdvancedClass`. However, what you *can* do is create a new `AdvanceClass` using the instance of `BaseClass` as an initializer.

For example:

```
BaseClass* baseInstance = [[BaseClass alloc] init];
...
AdvancedClass* advancedInstance = [[AdvancedClass alloc] initWithBaseClass:baseInstance];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly accepted to create a class which is a subclass of another class.
In alternative, you might want to use categories:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I'm aware with subclassing as its shown in question.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you was aware about Object Oriented programming and Polymorphism, I just wanted to point out some alternatives peculiar to Objective-C